# How to replace a variable value with the value plus stuff in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am not sure how to state this.

Say you have a math equation as a string:

```
String equation = "2 3 - 6 + 5 ( 4 - 3 )";
```

What I want to do is replace all the numbers that are next to each other or next to a parenthesis with the same content but with a `*` between them. So `"2 3 - 6 + 5 ( 4 - 3 )"` becomes `"2 * 3 - 6 + 5 * ( 4 - 3 )"`.

Is there a way to do this without loops? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a clearer example?

Comment: do some research around regex, pattern, string replacment, string matching etc.  read [ask].

Comment: Using loops is likely to be the simplest options, and writing a loop is trivial compared with writing a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with an according [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) with capturing groups and use `$1` and `$2` in the replacement to reuse the strings in the captured groups.

```
String equation = "2 x - 6 + 5 ( 4 - 3 ) y";
String regex = "([0-9xyz)])\\s*([0-9xyz(])";
String replaced = equation.replaceAll(regex, "$1 * $2");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output:

```
2 * x - 6 + 5 * ( 4 - 3 ) * y
```